# « L'essentiel est que vous soyez arrivés » : pourquoi le subjonctif ?

Tags: grammaire, subjonctif

> L'essentiel est que vous **soyez** arrivés

Pouvez-vous m'expliquer pourquoi on utilise le subjonctif dans la phrase ci-dessus ?

Ai-je raison de dire que, si on écrivait plutôt : *Ce qui est essentiel, c'est que vous êtes arrivés*, on utiliserait l'indicatif et pas le subjonctif ?

Comment: Une modification a été faite dans la question. On est passé de "L'essentiel est que vous soyez arrivé" à "L'essentiel est que vous soyez arrivés". Pourtant, l'accord au singulier est possible dans la cas d'un "vous" de politesse, non?

Comment: @Djaian absolument, mais le manque de contexte tend à faire penser à la 2ème personne du pluriel "par défaut" plutôt qu'à un vouvoiement.

Comment: @Alexis Pigeon Certes, toutefois éditer une question pour corriger une faute qui n'en est pas forcément une me semble dangereux. La personne qui a posé la question pourrait croire que sa phrase contenait une faute alors que non. Dans l'exemple, si je ne suis pas de langue maternelle française et que je pose cette question, après la modification je pourrais être amené à croire que l'on accorde le participe passé y compris dans le cas d'un vouvoiement de politesse.

Comment: @Djaian: je suis d'accord avec toi, merci de le faire remarquer. J'avoue que j'ai modifié le titre après avoir vu que le corps avait été modifié pour ajouter le "s", je n'ai pas pensé à cet accord au singulier possible. Libre à Sarastro de re-modifier sa question :)

Comment: En fait, dans le livre d'où la phrase vient, celui-ci s'agit seulement d'une personne, mais ce n'est pas grave.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C'est un des cas où le subjonctif et l'indicatif sont tous deux possibles. Grevisse, après avoir donné des règles pour le choix du mode dans les propositions conjonctives essentielles, règles d'ailleurs souvent exprimées de manière particulièrement peu normative même pour lui, continue en disant

> Les autres propositions sujets sont d'ordinaire à l'indicatif, mais le subjonctif apparaît parfois quand on ne s'engage pas sur la réalité du fait (parfois aussi dans des cas où il ne s'explique pas vraiment)

et suivent une série d'exemples les uns avec de l'indicatif, les autres avec le subjonctif.  Deux d'entre eux sont formés sur le modèle « l'essentiel est que ... » utilisant chacun un mode différent.

Comment: *L'essentiel est que vous êtes arrivé(s) ?* Je ne trouve pas la formule très naturelle.

Answer (score 1):

Dans la phrase :

> L'essentiel est que vous soyez arrivés.

Ici, on pense à une chose qui aurait pu arriver à ces personnes. Si elles avaient subit cette chose, elles ne seraient peut-être pas arrivées. Il y a une supposition pour qu'elles soient bien arrivées. Cette supposition est qu'il ne leur est rien arrivé. C'est pourquoi on emploie le subjonctif.

Dans la phrase :

> Ce qui est essentiel, c'est que vous êtes arrivés.

Cette phrase n'est pas correcte, on doit aussi employer ici le subjonctif.

Comment: Désolé, mais je ne comprends pas très bien comment vous voulez dire par *mais les personnes sont **passées outre** et sont donc arrivées*, la part en gras en particulier. Veuillez les traduire en anglais s'il vous plaît. Pouvez-vous aussi expliquer la différence entre la phrase originale et la phrase alternative que j'ai donnée, en ce qui concerne l'emploi du subjonctif? Merci.

Comment: J'ai édité ma réponse pour être plus clair.